# Game abbreviations in regards to search engines

Tags: discussion

Thinking about a game like Team Fortress 2.  On message boards about the game, it's normally referred to as TF2.  We have a tag that is 'team-fortress-2' for this game.

If someone is searching for 'tf2 heavy' on Google, it's very unlikely they would find their way here.  Is there any way we can seamlessly embed these abbreviations into a question/tag/post?

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-tag-use-acronyms-or-not with regards to tags specifically, and some of the discussion at http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38/tag-question-wow-or-world-of-warcraft covers search concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For writing clarity, I always try to **spell out the full name followed by the abbreviation in parenthesis the first time it appears**. Then the remainder of the article can use the abbreviation. It's clear to the reader what you are talking about and that takes care of the Google-search problem.

> I'm having a problem with Team Fortress 2 (TF2). Ever since I've started using TF2 on the Mac, Heavy's gun is not as responsive as it should be.

Please **use the wiki features of this site** to add these types of edits to any post. It makes the answer better for *everyone.*

Comment: Isn't really easy for anyone to "use the wiki features of this site" since nobody on the site currently has 2k rep.

Comment: @Arda Xi: That's a temporary situation. We're talking about how to create an effective site, even if we can't fix every single post right now.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Google is smart, as the first result when searching for TF2 is actually, the official Team Fortress 2 website.

Also, using full names, and not abbreviations will help search engines determine what you actually mean, for example, does SMG mean Submachine Gun or Super Mario Galaxy.

However, the best example can be found in the PS abbreviation, as google recognizes it as both PlayStation as well as PhotoShop, using PlayStation instead of PS will let google know we mean PlayStation and not PhotoShop, resulting in a more accurate interpretation. (meaning it is better for SEO)

Comment: According to Google's first result, SMG stands for Scotts Miracle-Gro.

Comment: Isn't that because when people link to the Official site they link to it as TF2. Google bombing or something was related to that.

Comment: i've noticed the same thing with "ps3"--google knows that it is the same as "playstation 3"

Comment: @kip thanks for the PS3 example, added some info about the PS keyword too :D

Comment: I confirm it. I have a blog on TF2 and the visits generated by Google are more less equal with the two terms.

Answer (score 1):

Tag synonyms [are in the works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56685/tag-synonyms-the-user-experience). A synonym between `Team Fortress 2` and `TF2` might fix this, depending on how it's implemented.